# Custom button panUp panDown panLeft panRight google map api v3 event.addDomListener dont work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add **event** to button image to move the pan of my **map up left right down** the zoom work fine, but the move not. Thanks for help. I'm in API v3 so if you have any idea how can I create new button image for navigation of the map, it will be helpful to:

```
var panUp = document.createElement("div");
          this.setButtonStyle_(panUp);
          control2.appendChild(panUp);
          panUp.appendChild(document.createTextNode("panUp"));
          panUp.innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/map_arrow_up.png">'; 
          g.event.addDomListener(panUp, "click", function() {
          map.setpanBy(new Point(-100, 0));

          });
var panDown = document.createElement("div");
          this.setButtonStyle_(panDown);
          control3.appendChild(panDown);
          panDown.appendChild(document.createTextNode("panDown"));
          panDown.innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/map_arrow_down.png">'; 
          g.event.addDomListener(panDown, "click", function() {
          map.panDirection(0,-1); 
          });

          var panLeft = document.createElement("div");
          this.setButtonStyle_(panLeft);
          control4.appendChild(panLeft);
          panLeft.appendChild(document.createTextNode("panLeft"));
          panLeft.innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/map_arrow_left.png">'; 
          g.event.addDomListener(panLeft, "click", function() {
          map.panDirection(1,0);  
          });

          var panRight = document.createElement("div");
          this.setButtonStyle_(panRight);
          control5.appendChild(panRight);
          panRight.appendChild(document.createTextNode("panRight"));
          panRight.innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/map_arrow_right.png">'; 
          g.event.addDomListener(panRight, "click", function() {
          map.panDirection(-1,0); 
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no methods **setpanBy** or **panDirection** in V3, you may use **panBy()** or **panTo()**

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map